# X509 client-certificate not found in Jetty 11

Tags: jetty, client-certificates

After a recent upgrade from Jetty 10 to Jetty 11 we have a problem with connections that use a client certificate. The client certificate used to be available in a request attribute "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate", but since Jetty 11 this is not longer the case. Is this is a bug or is there another way to obtain the client certificate in Jetty 11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the anwser in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer`. In Jetty 11 the attribute name for the client certificate has changed from "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate" to "jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate".

Comment: As documented in https://github.com/jakartaee/servlet/blob/5.0.0-RELEASE/spec/src/main/asciidoc/servlet-spec-body.adoc#310-ssl-attributes